# How to handle time sliders in JavaScript which can be moved from both left and right

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working in JavaScript and have a time slider that can be adjusted from both left and right.can some one please suggest how do I handle this ? Found few answers with java but I am looking for solution in JavaScript
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to handle time sliders. you will need to have 2 elements 1 for left and 1 for right and adjust the x,y coordinates. [element2 is your webelement]

```
const actions3 = driver.actions({
                    bridge: true
                });

                await actions3.dragAndDrop(
                    element2, {
                        x: -120,
                        y: -120
                    }
                ).perform();
```